# How to reference jar files after sbt publish-local

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

The spark jars have been successfully published to the local repository:

```
sbt publish-local
```

Here is an excerpt for the spark-core -  things look healthy:

> [info]  published spark-core_2.10 to
>   C:\Users\s80035683.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.10\1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\spark-core_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
>   [info]  published spark-core_2.10 to
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.10\1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\poms\spark-core_2.10.pom
>   [info]  published spark-core_2.10 to
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.10\1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\jars\spark-core_2.10.jar
>   [info]  published spark-core_2.10 to
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.10\1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\srcs\spark-core_2.10-sources.jar
>   [info]  published spark-core_2.10 to
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.10\1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\docs\spark-core_2.10-javadoc.jar
>   [info]  published ivy to
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.10\1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml

In particular: here is one file in the .m2:

```
C:\Users\s80035683\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.10\1.1.0-SNAPSHOT>dir

 Directory of C:\Users\s80035683\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.10\1.1.0-SNAPSHOT

06/26/2014  04:25 PM    <DIR>          .
06/26/2014  04:25 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/26/2014  04:25 PM         1,180,476 spark-core_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
06/26/2014  04:24 PM           808,815 spark-core_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
06/26/2014  02:27 PM         5,781,917 spark-core_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
06/26/2014  05:03 PM            13,436 spark-core_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

The problem comes when trying to **consume** the jars in a client project.

Here is an excerpt from the client build.sbt:

```
val sparkVersion = "1.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
..
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % sparkVersion  % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % sparkVersion  % "compile->default"  withSources()

..

resolvers  ++= Seq(
  "Apache repo" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "Local Repo" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + "/.m2/repository",
  Resolver.mavenLocal
)
```

So: we have :

- a good local repo
- a build.sbt that references the local repo

But when we do:

```
sbt package
```

We get unresolved dependency on the same spark artifacts that we just published:

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\apps\hspark\project
[info] Set current project to hspark (in build file:/C:/apps/hspark/)
[info] Updating {file:/C:/apps/hspark/}hspark...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
  [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: configuration not found in org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 'default'. It was required from default#hspark_2.10;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT compile
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: configuration not found in org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 'default'. It was required from default#hspark_2.10;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: configuration not found in org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 'default'. It was required from default#hspark_2.10;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT compile
unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: configuration not found in org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 'default'. It was required from default#hspark_2.10;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT compile
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
..
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: configuration not found in org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 'default'. It was required from default#hspark_2.10;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT compile
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: configuration not found in org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 'default'. It was required from default#hspark_2.10;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT compile

[
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: configuration not found in org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 'default'. It was required from default#hspark_2.10;0.1.0-SNAPSHO
```

**UPDATE**  Based on answer by @lpiepiora  it seems removing the compile-> default does (surprisingly) make the difference. Here is the evidence so far.

(Using the dependency-graph plugin):

> Done updating. [info] default:hspark_2.10:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT [S] [info]
>   +-org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT [S]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing mapping `compile->default` for your dependencies. It is redundant anyway, as the documentation says:

> A configuration without a mapping (no "->") is mapped to "default" or
>   "compile". The -> is only needed when mapping to a different
>   configuration than those.

Therefore declare your dependencies as follows:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % sparkVersion withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % sparkVersion  withSources()
)
```

and they should resolve.

Comment: This seems to be working. I am doing a bit more validations. Expect an accept soon.

Comment: Actually this does not appear to be working . Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes, I have. Published localy and had another project using it. I will test it again and put it somewhere. So maybe you can test it on your configuration.

Comment: "sparkVersion withSources()" was not working. I had to remove the withSources()

Comment: @javadba it works for me - what error did  you get when using `withSources()` ? I'm using sbt 0.13.5.

Comment: the errors may have had to do with some of Intellij (many..) weirdness'es.  I will update after the dust settles

Comment: @javadba that could be the reason. I'm using it just from the console.

Comment: i have upvoted but will still do bit more testing before accept